# Why do I need to initialize fn3 (variable) before I could use fn3 outside loop?

Tags: java

The program works fine. But if fn3 is not initialized and I try to access fn3 outside loop, compiler throws "*variable fn3 might not have been initialized*". Why fn3 should be declared and initialized?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GenerateFibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("Enter the limit of Fibonacci series: ");
        int limit = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The first " + limit + "Fibonacci numbers are : ");

        int fn2=0, fn1=1, fn3=0;

        for(int i=0; i<=limit;i++) {
            if(i <= 1) {
                fn3 = i;
            }
            else {
                fn3 = fn2+fn1;
                fn2 = fn1;
                fn1 = fn3;  
            }

            System.out.println(fn3 + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println("The average is " + fn3/limit);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Because JLS §16 says so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-16.html): "***For every access of a local variable or blank final field `x`, `x` must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.***"

Comment: There's a possibility that your for loop may not run once, therefore would be trying to access a variable before it's given a value.  Initializing variables as they are declared avoids that.

Comment: In other words, what would happen if `limit` were zero (or negative)?

Answer (score 1):

Local variables must be initialized before use. They don't have a default value and contain garbage data until initialized. Whereas,

Instance and class variables don't require you to initialize them. As soon as you declare these variables, they are given a default value.

Answer (score 0):

As @anoopknr says, local variables must be initialized before they are used.

But, there is more to it than this.  The compiler must know that the variable will be initialized before it is using *in every possible execution*.

In this version of the code:

```
    int fn2 = 0, fn1 = 1, fn3;

    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
        if (i <= 1) {
            fn3 = i;
        }
        else {
            fn3 = fn2 + fn1;
            fn2 = fn1;
            fn1 = fn3;  
        }
        System.out.println(fn3 + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("The average is " + (fn3 / limit));
```

... it is possible to reach the `println` without `fn3` being initializes, even though `fn3` is assigned in every loop iteration.  Consider the case where `limit` is negative.  Then `0 <= limit` will be `false` and the loop body will not be executed.  If the body is not executed that the assignments to `fn3` won't occur.

In fact, the requirement is stronger than "must be initialized".  The variable has to be *definitely assigned*.  There is a [complete chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-16.html) in the JLS that specifies what this means, but in this case the loop body does not perform definite assignment ... even if we could prove that `limit` is always non-negative.